# Bootstrap dropdown gets clipped inside div with overflow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is well discussed topic on SO but i still could not figure out how do i solve this issue.

I have [bootstrap dropdown](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) inside a `div` that has `overflow-y` property set to auto. And because of overflow property the drop down gets clipped.

the container `div` can have any number of controls. So if the height of thecontainer `div` goes beyond viewport then container should get vertical scrollbar. So the following css is set on container `div`

```
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 80vh;
```

But then adding overflow-y causing dropdown  to clipped.

https://jsfiddle.net/yrqasva2/7/

**Update 1 - Some more description of the issue**
I am dynamically adding controls into `pabel-body` so the `panel-body` can have one or more controls. So when panel-body has more controls the `panel-body` may go below view-port and without `overflow-y: auto` you will see browser's vertical scroll bar.

I DO NOT want browser's scroll bar, instead i want `panel-body` scroll bar. So i set the max-height of the `panel-body` to 80%. ( the remaining 20% is allocated to page header and stuff). So now panel-body get vertical scrollbar only when its height becomes more that 80% of the view-port.

This is working fine. But because of that drop down gets clipped.

Comment: Of course it is, you have set the max height to be 80vh and set the container to use overflow vertically. Are you asking how to make the container resize depending on the size of the screen?

Comment: the property max-height: 80vh; will be redundant without assigning it a height. since you've set overflow-y: auto; then the div will never resize, instead it would just throw in a scroll. if you remove overflow-y: auto; then  the dropdown will show outside the container.... what's the precise behavior you are looking for? you want the DIV to expand max to 80vh AND show scroll?

Comment: please see my update 1

Comment: Is your problem solved right now?